# How to access the modules deployed to the FINAL database in DatahubFramework

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I'm working with the Marklogic's DatahubFramework and I deployed the self made Javascript modules. When I invoke this resources through the 8010 port (STAGING DB) everythings seems to work fine but when the 8011 port (FINAL DB) is invoked I get always the same error:

> "RESTAPI-INVALIDREQ: (err:FOER0000) Invalid request:  reason: Extension test or a dependency does not exist: XDMP-MODNOTFOUND: (err:XQST0059) Module /marklogic.rest.resource/test/assets/resource.xqy not found . See the MarkLogic server error log for further detail."

The endpoint I'm invoking is the "http://localhost:8011/v1/resources/searchEvents"

How to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked in which database `/marklogic.rest.resource/test/assets/resource.xqy` is located ? Is this database the modules database of your final db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, the gradle script "gradle mlDeploy" filled the property *url rewriter* with the wrong value and it was referencing another rewriter file. After fixing this value, everything worked as planned.

Comment: I wonder though, how could that property end up wrong? Was it migrated from an earlier version of the datahub?